# Laravel Swagger best practice

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, laravel-5.8

We are using https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger in our Laravel project.

Currently we add all annotations directly to the controller, it is ok but,  makes code bit messy. I was wondering what are the best practices? Maybe it is better to keep annotations in separated file?

Some one can share code example how to keep annotations in separated file?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Did you find a better solution than adding annotations directly in controller?

Comment: @Dark73 not really... but I think using an interface and putting docs there is a good idea, recently I found this approach in Java Spring boot